# ubuntu 14.04 firefox starting without sudo gives security library failure on SSL sites

Tags: firefox, security

I have a problem with ubuntu desktop 14.04. 
When executing `firefox` without `sudo`, then all the https sites (even http://google.com) gives me

```
Error code: sec_error_library_failure
```

But when executing from the terminal `sudo firefox`, then it's all fine and all the https webpages load without a problem.

I'm guessing it a file ownership issue somewhere, but I cannot figure out (even with googles help) where it is located. I've tried to `chown` every directory and file to the specific user where Firefox is located (with the help of "whereis firefox" command) but still no help.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: What version of Firefox are you running?

Comment: Also read [why not to use sudo for gui apps](http://askubuntu.com/q/270006/164891), this is interesting and might point to how you got this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just encountered this same issue, and resolved it without refreshing Firefox.  I noticed that in my Firefox profile, all files were still owned by me, except revocations.txt (now owned by root).

Try running:

```
find .mozilla/firefox/ -user root
```

If you find the same results I did, chown revocations.txt back to your user account:

```
sudo chown user:user .mozilla/firefox/profile.default/revocations.txt
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks this helped me a lot, I couldn't figure out what it was!

Comment: Thanks @square! Thanks to you I understand the reason of my issue. First I thought that this is not my case and I was sure owner of all firefox profile's files was my user but not the root. 

*But then I remember that earlier I ran `sudo webpack --watch` when doing some programming job and my app also had `browsersync` which started firefox browser on initialization. So yes, browser was started under the root, created some files with `root` owner and then when I tried to open it under the my user I got the error `Secure Connection Failed SEC_ERROR_LIBRARY_FAILURE`!*

Answer (score 2):

https://support.mozilla.org/ru/questions/1058797
To Refresh Firefox:

Open the Troubleshooting Information page using one of these methods:
Click the menu button ￼ , click help ￼ and select Troubleshooting Information. A new tab containing your troubleshooting information should open.
If you're unable to access the Help menu, type about:support in your address bar to bring up the Troubleshooting Information page.
At the top right corner of the page, you should see a button that says "Refresh Firefox" ("Reset Firefox" in older Firefox versions). Click on it.
Firefox will close. After the refresh process is completed, Firefox will show a window with the information that is imported.
Click Finish and Firefox will reopen.
Did this fix the problem? Please report back to us!

Thank you.